# why is "error:&error" used here (objective-c)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pass-by-reference, nserror

why is "error:&error" used here (objective-c)

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

wouldn't an object in objective-c be effectively pass-by-reference anyway?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The argument type for `error:` is `NSError**` (i.e. a *pointer* to a pointer to an object). This permits the `moc` object to allocate and initialize a new `NSError` object as required. It is a common pattern, especially in Cocoa.

The [NSError documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html) gives some indication of the motivation for this approach:

> Applications may choose to create subclasses of NSError to provide better localized error strings by overriding [localizedDescription](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSError/localizedDescription).

Passing in an `NSError**` argument allows that method to return any subclass of `NSError` that makes sense. If you passed in `NSError*`, you would have to supply an existing `NSError` object, and there would be no way for the method to return a *different* object from the one you passed in.

To be clear, the method could look something like this:

```
- (NSArray*)executeFetchRequest:(Request *)request error:(NSError**)error {
    ...
    if ((error != NULL) && (some_error_condition)) {
        *error = [[[SomeNSErrorSubclass alloc] init...] autorelease];
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Note that this also allows the calling code to ignore errors by simply passing in `NULL` for the `error:` parameter, as follows:

```
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
```

***Update:*** (in response to questions):

There are two reasons why the argument type has to be `NSError**` instead of `NSError*`: 1. variable scoping rules, and 2. NSError instances are imutable.

*Reason #1: variable scoping rules*

Let's assume that the function declaration were to look like this:

```
- (NSArray*)executeFetchRequest:(Request *)request error:(NSError*)error;
```

And we were to call the function like this:

```
NSError * error = nil;
[someArray executeFetchRequest:someRequest error:error];
if (error != nil) { /* handle error */ }
```

When you pass in a variable this way, the function body will not be able to modify the *value* of that variable (i.e. the function body will not be able to create a new variable to replace the existing one). For example, the following variable assignments will exist only in the local scope of the function. The calling code will still see `error == nil`.

```
- (NSArray*)executeFetchRequest:(Request *)request error:(NSError*)error {
    ...
    error = [[[NSError alloc] init...] autorelease];             // local only
    error = [[[SomeNSErrorSubclass alloc] init...] autorelease]; // local only
}
```

*Reason #2: instances of NSError are immutable*

Let's keep the same function declaration, but call the function like this:

```
NSError * error = [[[NSError alloc] init...] autorelease];
[someArray executeFetchRequest:someRequest error:error];
if (error != nil) { /* handle error */ }
```

First of all, the variable scoping rules guarantee that `error` can not be `nil`, so the `if (error != nil) { ...` condition will always be true, but even if you wanted to check for specific error information inside the `if` block, you would be out of luck because instances of `NSError` are *immutable*. This means that once they are created, you cannot modify their properties, so the function would not be able to change the `domain` or `userInfo` of that `NSError` instance that you created in the calling code.

```
- (NSArray*)executeFetchRequest:(Request *)request error:(NSError*)error {
    ...
    error.domain = ...   // not allowed!
    error.userInfo = ... // not allowed!
}
```

Comment: @Kevin Ballard: That's true. It should be an `autoreleased` object. I have changed it.

Comment: Im almost getting this.  Just one question...why this = "and there would be no way for the method to return a different object from the one you passed in". IOW, why do we need a different object than the one passed in? Thx in advance

Comment: @marciokoko: The answer was too long for a comment, so I added it above. Hope that helps!

Comment: WOW!  I actually think I understand it :-) You need to create an error instance to fill it when the method returns. Since you don't know what error it will be, you must be able to modify it somehow. But NSError instances are immutable & furthermore cannot be changed in-scope, so we pass a pointer to a pointer. Last Q, couldnt we just create the NSError instance inside the method?

Comment: @marciokoko: Glad to hear it! `:)`. The NSError instance should definitely be created inside the method, but it will only exist in local scope unless you use the NSError** argument. You can try that one out for yourself with a simple function in a test program if that helps?

Comment: Could you join this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35802/ios-pointer-to-a-pointer

Comment: @e.James "if ((error != NULL) && (some_error_condition)) " should read "if ((*error != NULL) && (some_error_condition)) "

Answer (score 3):

It's effectively another return value. The error is not dominant by convention in Cocoa when there is a return value for the operation. When an error is encountered, it may be returned to you by this out parameter.

In the case of `NSError`, it works this way because `NSError` is *not* a mutable type - its fields are set at initialization and never mutated. Therefore, you cannot pass an `NSError` as usual and set the error code.

Comment: +1 for describing `error:(NSError**)error` as an out parameter, and for explaining that `NSError` objects cannot be mutated after initialization. I missed both of these in my answer.