# Swift Pass array by reference to ObjectiveC method

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

I just want to know how may I pass an array from Swift class to Objective C class by reference. I have idea for Swift to Swift by reference using `inout` keyword. But as ObjC uses pointers itself as object names. How may I inform Swift to pass the object by reference Instead of Value?

**Code Snipshot**

Swift:

```
class CheckReference: NSObject {    
    class func test() {

        let array : NSMutableArray! = nil
        ViewController.change(array) //ViewController.change(&array) doesn't work
        print(array)//does not changed 
    }
}
```

Objective C:

```
 + (void)changeArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
    if(!array)    
        array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [array addObject:@(2)];
}
```

**Edit:**
For swift it works by changing methods as: But still Objective C interaction is not working.

```
class func test() {
    var array : NSMutableArray! = nil
    CheckReference.passByReference(arr: &array)
    print(array ?? "nothing")//prints 2

}
class func passByReference(arr: inout NSMutableArray!)
{
    arr = NSMutableArray()
    arr.add(2)
}
```

Comment: Just convert it to `NSMutableArray` if you want to send to obj-c function

Comment: even tried that as well. Updated question

Comment: it still passes it by value.

Comment: Hm...have you tried to create the array in swift then pass it to obj-c? Your code above seems should be working though

Comment: yup. Tried. It creates another copy and the original has nothing changed in it

Comment: You are passing `nil`, which means that a new array is created in the Obj-C method (and not passed back). With `let array = NSMutableArray()` in the Swift code it should work.

Comment: @MartinR yeah it worked. The same thing said by Tj3n

Comment: @Tj3n you can put this to answer I'll accept it. My Bad I didn't noticed this nil thing :)

Comment: guys one more thing. How Objective C handles then nil Pointers and returns objects in it??? e.g. passing an NSError = nil object and get a valid memory obtained object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so my guess is that when you are passing `nil`, you are NOT passing a pointer, since its not pointing to anything, thus your value after that, does not changed.

If you want to pass `nil`, you may have to change the function to return a pointer to new `NSMutableArray`, and assign back to the `array` in your swift code

Create `array` first in Swift and pass to Obj-c ensure the object has been created and passing proper pointer

Comment: Solved my problem but How Objective C handles then nil Pointers and returns objects in it??? e.g. passing an NSError = nil object and get a valid memory obtained object?

Comment: `NSError` handling is more like `inout`, remember the `&` when you need to hook the `NSError` variable? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061381/what-does-error-mean-in-objective-c) might help understand, for other case I think its just the different between swift and obj-c compiler against each other