# Copying from "id" variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have created a class `NetCalculator` which I am calling when a button is pressed. The method calculate network it gets 2 `NSString`s and returns an `id` object (either "Network" object or "UIAlertView". Then I am checking which object is and I present the data. When I am using the `UIAlertView` the app is crashing after showing 2-3 alerts.

Any ides why this happens? On terminal it doesnt show any error just some random hexadecimal.

```
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
    id result;

    Network *network = [[Network alloc]init];

    NetCalculator *netCalculated = [[NetCalculator alloc] init];
    result = [netCalculated calculateNetworkWithIP:ipLabel.text andSubnet:subnetLabel.text];

    if([result isKindOfClass:[Network class]]){
        network = result;
        NSLog(@"network %@",network.networkIP);    
    }

    else if([result isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) {

        UIAlertView *alert;
        alert = result;

        [alert show];    
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the reason for the crash? What is the stack trace?

Comment: Should you allocate and initialize your UIAlertView object?

Comment: Try to NSLog your result variable and see what it is.

Comment: where do you retain the alertView?

Comment: the issue seems to be that it is deallocated randomly in  the bg.. well at least in 99% of those cases that is the issue

Comment: @op please show where you create the alert and where you retain/release it -- are you using arc or mrc?

Comment: @sha I did an nslog "<UIAlertView: 0x89a72e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x89a2370>>" at flexaddicted Do you mean that my class is wrong? I mean is it wrong to return an alertview if something went wrong?

Comment: @Daij-Djan the alert is created inside the NetworkCalculator Class that way: "UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@...." and then I return that.

Comment: and Right after alloc/init it is shown? once? or n times? Create-Show-Create-Show works Create-show-show doesn't.

Comment: I am returning it and then I am checking what kind of class it is (check it on my code). It's shows ok but after pressing ok is crashing

Comment: @JoshValdivieso If `[result isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]` evaluates to true, then the UIAlertView object is initialized correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is quite strange to me. Your method `calculateNetworkWithIP` could return a `Network` result or a `UIAlertView` result. I wouldn't follow such an approach.

If the problem relies on memory you should show us hot that method is implemented.

Anyway, I would propose some changes (*The following code does not take into account ARC or non ARC code*). In particular, I would modify the `calculateNetworkWithIP` to return a `Network` result. An error will populated if a problem arises and it is passed as an argument.

```
- (Network*) calculateNetworkWithIP:(NSString *)ip subnet:(NSString*)subnet error:(NSError**)error
```

If all is ok, the result would be be a `Network` and so print it or reused it somewhere. Otherwise an `NSError` would be returned and based on that create and show an alert view.

So, here pseudo code to do it.

```
NetCalculator *netCalculated = [[NetCalculator alloc] init];

NSError* error = nil;
Network* networkResult = [netCalculated calculateNetworkWithIP:ipLabel.text subnet:subnetLabel.text error:&error];

if(error != nil) {
    // create and show an alert view with the error you received
} else {
    // all ok so, for example, save the result in a instance variable
}
```

To follow a similar approach you can take a look at [why is "error:&error" used here (objective-c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334518/why-is-errorerror-used-here-objective-c).

Comment: Your answer looks good but since I am unfamiliar with creating my own NSErrors what should my method return in case of error? The method expects Network object so I will return nil? Also how I will pass the error in the "error" variable?

Comment: I tried returning nil and initializing the error in the NetworkCalculator by doing this:             error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"some error" code:5 userInfo:nil]; but the "error" is still nil in the main

Comment: I found the problem. I was using NSError instead of NSError*. Thank you